# ExtJS combobox filter

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, combobox

I have two comboboxes. The first one is for selecting a **region**, and the second one is for selecting a **province**. The values that should appear in the province combobox will be based on the value selected in the region combobox.

Region combobox code:

```
xtype: 'combobox',
label: 'Region ID',
margin: '10 20',
flex: 1,
valueField: 'regionid',
displayField: 'regionname',
store: 'RegionStore',
minLength: 1,
id: 'region_id',
reference: 'region_id',
name: 'region_id',
listeners: {
  select: function(combo, value) {
    var id = Ext.getCmp('province'),
    store = id.getStore();

    if (!value) {
      store.getFilters().removeAll();
    } 
    else {
      store.filter('regionid', val)
    }
  }
}
```

Province combobox code:

```
label: 'Province',
margin: '10 20',
flex: 1,
queryMode: 'remote',
store: 'ProvinceStore',
valueField: 'provinceid',
displayField: 'provincename',
minLength: 1,
id: 'province',
name: 'province',
reference: 'province'
```

I'm not getting any errors but when I click the province combobox(assuming that I have already selected a value for the region combobox), the values displayed in the province combobox are not filtered, instead, all of the results are displayed. I have been on this for days. Is there someone who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `queryMode: 'remote'`, so that your server returns the data.
The frontend has no control, what is returned.

Plus in your example `val` should be `value`.

I would go with a chained store, that has a filter based on the selection.

Here is a fiddle to show this:
[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/327h)

This is duplicate to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59460330/extjs-chained-store-filter-not-filtering/)

Comment: Hi, I'm getting "TypeError: store is null" when I put filteredStore as my store

Comment: Please take a look. Updated the fiddle. You need to set `queryMode: 'local'`. Does that help?

Comment: Hi. It helped, but I am getting a different error instead. TypeError: source.load is not a function

Comment: I've solved it by placing the filter inside the city store. Thank you so much for your help :D