# ExtJS chained store filter not filtering

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, viewmodel

Filter for combobox is not working and I am not sure why. I have two comboboxes, one is **province** and other is **city**. When I select a province, the city combobox will be filtered according to the selected province using the province_id.

View Model Code:

```
data: {
selectedProvince: null
},

stores: {
  province: {
    fields: [ 'province_id', 'province_name' ],
    proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      url: '*some url to province*',
      reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'data'
      }
    }
  },

  city: {
    fields: [ 'city_id', 'city_name', 'province_id' ],
        proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      url: '*some url to city*',
      reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'data',
      }
    },

  },

  filteredStore: {
    type: 'chained',
    source: '{city}',
    remoteFilter: false,
    filters: [{
      property: 'province_id',
      value: '{selectedProvince}'
    }],

  }
}
```

Province Combobox Code:

```
xtype: 'combobox',
label: 'Province',
valueField: 'province_id',
displayField: 'province_name',
bind: {
  store: '{province}',
  value: '{selectedProvince}'
}
```

City Combobox Code:

```
xtype: 'combobox',
label: 'City',
valueField: 'city_id',
displayField: 'city_name',
bind: {
  store: '{filteredStore}'
}
```

I have tried these:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/983&view/editor

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2dt0

And I have also tried placing the filter inside the combobox like this:

```
xtype: 'combobox',
label: 'City',
valueField: 'city_id',
displayField: 'city_name',
bind: {
   store: '{filteredStore}',
   filters: {
      property: 'province_id',
      value: '{selectedProvince}'
    }
 }
```

And still, the results are still not filtered. I'm using extjs 7, if that helps. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ExtJS combobox filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59439273/extjs-combobox-filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59439273/extjs-combobox-filter/59444305):

The answer is still in this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/327h)

I updated it to match your question in this thread.

You have to set both stores to `autoLoad: true` and the combobox to `queryMode: 'local'`.